# Надо синонимизировать метки [cross-compiling] и [кросс-компиляция]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки

- [cross-compiling](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-compiling) (47 вопросов)
- [кросс-компиляция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (28 вопросов)

Основная - [кросс-компиляция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (она на русском).

Comment: Предложил описание: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/875944.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово:

```
updating post history, 44 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 47 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 42 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'cross-compiling': [cross-compiling] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 70
tag remapping of [кросс-компиляция] and [cross-compiling] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
5 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym cross-compiling -> кросс-компиляция was approved!
```